# How install ImageMagic 6.6.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid)

Tags: linux, imagemagick

How install ImageMagic 6.6.2 on Ubuntu 10.04 (lucid)
Problem that lucid have old ImageMagic version(6.5.2)

Its very important because me need work with SVG grafics, In my local pc I have ubuntu 11.04 and ImageMagic 6.6.2 and all work fine, In server I have 6.5... and I have problem.
Reinstall ubuntu to 11.* this is no solution.

I tried change /etc/apt/source.list from ubuntu 10.04 (lucid) to list from ubuntu 11.04 (natty) and update ImageMagic. After this action I have ImageMagic 6.6.2 (I looked phpinfo())
but ImageMagick is not work now. If I try do any action I get error:

[error] 8996#0: *19983 FastCGI sent in stderr: "PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'ImagickException' with message 'no decode delegate for this image format `/tmp/magick-XXnYKWKC' @ error/constitute.c/ReadImage/532'

How it fix? Or how return to old version imagemagick?

Problem if I try install from sources:

```
 /tmp/image/ImageMagick-6.7.2-7# ./configure
 configuring ImageMagick 6.7.2-7
 checking build system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
 checking host system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
 checking target system type... i686-pc-linux-gnu
 checking whether build environment is sane... yes
 checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
 checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /bin/mkdir -p
 checking for gawk... no
 checking for mawk... mawk
 checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
 checking for style of include used by make... GNU
 checking for gcc... gcc
 checking whether the C compiler works... no
 configure: error: in `/tmp/image/ImageMagick-6.7.2-7':
 configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
 See `config.log' for more details
 /tmp/image/ImageMagick-6.7.2-7#
```

Answer (score 1):

Why is this a problem? It is a LTS version of Ubuntu so apparently you want to stick to stable versions (good choice). If you want to have newer version of ImageMagick then why not upgrade Ubuntu itself? Everything in between is unnecessary work combined with trouble.

By the way the version of ImageMagick on Ubuntu 10.04 is 6.5.7.8. So you have to update at least.

Answer (score 0):

The ImageMagick version in Ubuntu 10.04 is 6.5.7. Step 1 is to update your machine to that version. After that you have two paths to choose from:

- path 1: download all necessary .deb files from Ubuntu 11.04 repository. Check their dependencies and try to install them. There is a good chance you will run into some issues, as ImageMagick (or one of its libraries) depends on `libc6` and `libc-bin`;
- path 2: download the source code and compile it. This way you won't be able to update it when you update your distro, unless you produce .deb from the source code and install it via dpkg.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply compile the desired version of ImageMagick (possibly with a different prefix, if you don't want to mess with the system packages),

$ tar xvfz ImageMagick.tar.gz
$ cd ImageMagick-*
$ ./configure
$ make
$ sudo make install

Ref: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/install-source.php?ImageMagick=j5jdjn9mfvhul1r9rno3p50r85#unix